# How do I implmeent "join" in my Rails thread pool?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, join, pool

I'm using Rails 5.0 with Ruby 2.4.  I have this gem

```
gem 'concurrent-ruby'
```

I want to load up a thread pool with work, but then I don't want execution to continue unti everything in the thradpool has finished executing.  SO I tried this ...

```
  pool = Concurrent::FixedThreadPool.new(@concurrent_threads) 
  links.each do |link|
    pool.post do
      ... do work ...
    end 
  end
  pool.shutdown
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.  That is, there is code executed after the "pool.shutdown" line and I was hoping that would work somewhat like a ".join," that is, holding execution until everything had completed.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#wait_for_termination-instance_method), after calling `pool.shutdown`, you can call `pool.wait_for_termination` to block until all threads have completed.